# Inspect list of Celery jobs on command line

Tags: python, django, celery

In a Celery setup with Django, I registered two tasks, `email_slow_track` and `email_fast_track`. I would like to inspect the list of jobs for each task *on the command line*, but I was unable to find the right command.

Here's what I tried (my application name is `api`):

- `inspect registered`: This appears to list registered tasks, not jobs submitted under these tasks. **However,** it at least shows that the connection is set up properly, and that the tasks are known.

```
$ celery -A api inspect registered
-> celery@a5dac4396c0b: OK
    * api.celery.debug_task
    * email_fast_track [rate_limit=1/s]
    * email_slow_track [rate_limit=10/m]
```

- `inspect query_task <task_name>`: Empty result. I'm not sure what this command should do, and whether this is the expected result.

```
$ celery -A api inspect query_task email_slow_track
-> celery@a5dac4396c0b: OK
    {}
```

- `inspect query_task <task_id>`: Empty result. Just thought I'd give it a try ...

```
$ celery -A api inspect query_task cb1ecc1c-5746-4d08-ad50-4bff4d57855b
-> celery@a5dac4396c0b: OK
    {}
```

Note that my tasks do run properly. I'm not trying to fix task execution; the issue here is getting a list of tasks.

I am able to see all jobs with Celery Flower, so things are fine in general. But can I get that information from the command line?

---

Other things I attempted:

- `inspect active`: This is supposed to show tasks that a currently running. My tasks run really fast, so most of the time nothing is running. Any time I run this command, the result is empty.

```
$ celery -A api inspect active
-> celery@a5dac4396c0b: OK
    - empty -
```

- `inspect reserved`: This also often gives an empty result, or sometimes **one** task that has been fetched by a worker (just one in my case). But how do I get a list of all queue jobs?

Answer (score -2):

Celery does not provide command to get tasks in particular queue (for a good reason). Your question is not clear what you really want to achieve so I have to guess...

You say you can see the "list of jobs" in Flower. *Everything Flower can do is available via the inspect* because, guess what, Flower uses the inspect API (and Celery events which is the core of that service - that is how it is notified about all task events)!

`celery -A api inspect active` will give you a list of tasks that are currently running. Also useful is the `celery -A api inspect reserved` to find out which worker fetched which task (soon to be executed on that worker). The whole inspection API is available to you as well so that you can write more complex services.

Getting information what is in the queue is, in my humble opinion, useless information, as the moment you get the list, something will be taken out of it because the tasks will run and finish. It also depends on the broker. So in the case of Redis, each queue will have a LIST object in your Redis database that you can LLEN to find how how many tasks are waiting in that queue, or get those items to inspect tasks in that queue.

Let's say you want to check the number of tasks in the default (`celery` is the default name unless you changed it in your Celery configuration) queue. You do that via `LLEN celery`. To get the first task in that queue you execute `LINDEX celery 0`. However, as I mentioned above, after you executed LLEN, 1000 tasks may have allready been executed and removed from that list! That is probably why this feature is not available, and people do all sorts of hacks, like reading the queue backwards with `LINDEX celery -1` etc...

Comment: The result of this command is usually empty (tasks are short-running) or returns just one fetched task (I have one worker), even when a lot of tasks are queued. I edited my original question to contain this information. The original question still stands: How do I obtain a list of all jobs submitted?

Comment: Yes, the output depends on what is currently going on in your Celery cluster.

Comment: Well, in my use case, I know that my tasks run rarely due to the rate limit that I want to impose, and the task list would actually contain very useful information for me. It does not matter if this is a common Celery use case; the point is that this is simply what my question is. Flower can provide this information, so it is somehow accessible. I'd like to know if it can be done from the command line. It is possible that the answer to my question is "no, impossible from the command line". As it stands though, the question is still open.

Comment: Yes. The answer has information on "inspect active" and "inspect reserved" which gives other information, and it has Redis-specific information like LLEN and LINDEX. I don't use Redis, though, and the broker backend is immaterial to my question anyways. I asked a very specific question, and none of this is the answer to it. There is no information about which Celery CLI command to run in order to obtain the job list. Did I miss anything?